# iPhone keyboard shift key disabled

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, keyboard, shift

I have a `UITextField` where the keyboard that pops up has its <kbd>Shift</kbd> key disabled.  The keyboard type is set to `UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad`, which seems like it should allow capitals.

If I change the keyboard type to "default" but leave other settings alone, the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is active. The other settings are:

- autocapitalization and autocorrection off
- default appearance
- return key "done"

I'm running iPhone OS 2.2.

Has anyone seen this?  I don't understand why the "name phone pad" type would disable the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the logic behind this decision was, but *it does not look like there is a way to enable the shift key on this keyboard*.  I played around with this myself for a while, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707449/iphone-uikeyboardtypenamephonepad-with-shift-key) post that seems to agree. You may need to use the default keyboard and filter out any symbols you don't want (not ideal UI, but easy to do), or create a [custom keyboard](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/) ([example](https://github.com/lnafziger/Numberpad))