# iPhone UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad with shift key

Tags: iphone

I have a UITextField for a username, and I set the keyboard type to:

```
uiUsername.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad;
```

This way I can enter alphanumeric characters. But unfortunately the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is disabled. Is there a way to enable the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key using this keyboard type?

I know, I could set a different keyboard type and check for legal characters, but this keyboard type is very clean - only the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is missing.

Thanks for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, No, there is no way to enable the shift on this keyboard type.